# "Differences between states" is fine, but "differences between provinces and territories" is ambiguous. How to remove ambiguity?

Tags: sentence-structure, nouns, ambiguity, attachment-ambiguity

I always seem to fall into the following trap, and I would like to know what's the best way to avoid any ambiguity when comparing between different elements, where said elements belong to different groups:

> Developed a model to analyze and explain major policy trends, economic problems, and key **differences between provinces and territories** in terms of ...

The reader may very well think that I am talking about differences between *provinces* (group 1) and *territories* (group 2); so they may interpret this as, say, differences between *men* and *women*. But that is not my intention. In Canada, we have ten provinces and three territories. Let's call them "states". I want to make it clear that I am referring to the differences between the thirteen states.

The following reads perfectly fine:

> ... **differences between states in terms of** ...

The ambiguity arises because I have to respect the law of the land and distinguish between provinces and territories by clearly labelling them as such. What is the solution here?

Comment: This is also worth asking at [English Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, *differences between all the provinces and territories in terms of...*